# Unity DLL error when editing scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, unityscript

When I try to edit a script in Unity, I keep getting this error: "Unable to open UnityEngine.UI.dll: Check external applications preferences."

This also happens when I choose any other editor in the external tools preferences. I've tried setting up full permissions to this DLL file but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using windows 7 64 bit, and Unity 2017.1.0f3 Personal.

Comment: Did you try to delete 'Library','Temp' and 'Obj' folders from your project directories as well as all the .csproj files and .sln file, After that try to reopen the project from Unity. Be careful with deleting! if it works don't forget to upvote my comment. :)

Comment: What script are you trying to edit?

Comment: @Redouane, that didn't work at all, in fact it broke the project in several ways, luckly i backed it up.

Comment: @joreldraw, it's the basic c# script that Unity creates when you add a script component.

Comment: is a fresh installation in default folder?

Comment: @joreldraw yeap, fresh install and i downloaded the "space shooter" files to start that project

Comment: are you getting error if you open the csproj directly with VS or monodevelop? if yes, try associating the kind file to your editor, and .dll too.

Comment: @joreldraw  i would give it a try, but if it works it would be very awkward to code in VS and work the game in Unity :(

Comment: No, only re associate your files, and this fix the problem in some case. Right click , open with, and select your editor. Restart and try.

Comment: @joreldraw i've tried that but no luck so far. i've also tried with Beyond Compare 4 but the same error message displays. Which unity version do you recommend and where i can download it?. Thanks!

Comment: Im on Unity 5.6.3 withouth any problem, you can get here any older versión and try:
https://unity3d.com/es/get-unity/download/archive

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Change to unity 4.x and MonoDevelop start working.